# Java Chat Program Won't Print Message

Tags: java

I followed a YouTube tutorial for a Java Chat Application. It seemed to go well, except that when testing the program, the message wouldn't print to the screen. It's a fairly large project, so a Minimal Reproducible Example may be tough.

Any of the messages on the screen, even the "user connected" message will not display.

```java
public void send(String message) {
        try {

            if (!message.startsWith("\\")) {
                message = name + ": " + message;
            }
            byte[] data = message.getBytes();
            DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length, address, port);
            socket.send(packet);
            System.out.println("Sent message to " + address.getHostAddress() + ":" + port); 

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void listen() {
        Thread listenThread = new Thread("ChatProgram Listener") {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    while (running) {
                        byte[] data = new byte[1024];
                        DatagramPacket packet = new DatagramPacket(data, data.length);
                        socket.receive(packet);

                        String message = new String(data);
                        message = message.substring(0, message.indexOf("\\e"));

                        if (!isCommand(message, packet)) {
                        ClientWindow.printToConsole(message);
                    }
                    }

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }; listenThread.start();


        }

    private static boolean isCommand(String message, DatagramPacket packet) {
        if (message.startsWith("\\con:")) {

        }
            return true;

        }
```

I expect this to print the message to the screen, along with the username.

Sorry for the long MRE, but thanks in advance for the help! :)

Comment: Seeing that you have your prints inside of a try and catch, are you sure that an exception is not thrown and printing gets skipped?

Comment: @Bosco The line ```System.out.println("Sent message to"...``` is printed, indicating that a message was sent.

Comment: that's  UDP which is a connectionless protocol. how the user may ever connect to it?

Comment: @mangusta I don’t know much about java networking, all I do is regular Java/JavaFX. I’m net to networking, soI tried following a YouTube tutorial. Idk what i did wrong.

Comment: please upload the entry point of your program (for example main method), the information you have provided is too scarce. actually it looks a bit suspicious that the tutorial uses UDP for sending chat messages